# Зверюшки или зверушки?

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфография

Как правильно: зверУшки или зверЮшки? Или можно и так, и так?

Comment: Как правильно: "зверушки" или "зверьушки"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Лопатина оба варианта возможны: звер**у**шка, -и, р. мн. -шек и звер**ю**шка, -и, р. мн. -шек.

Answer (score -1):

Проверочным словом является *зверюга*.